# Using ResponsiveSlides.js, making slideshow stop after completed 1 loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, slideshow, responsive-slides

I am using http://responsiveslides.com/ to build a slideshow with custom navigation. I would love this navigation to run through once and then stop back at the first one. Any ideas on how to do this? This my JS for it (basically taken from their docs...).

Thanks in advance!

```
    $(".rslides").responsiveSlides({
      auto: true,             // Boolean: Animate automatically, true or false
      speed: 500,            // Integer: Speed of the transition, in milliseconds
      timeout: 4000,          // Integer: Time between slide transitions, in milliseconds
      pager: true,           // Boolean: Show pager, true or false
      nav: true,             // Boolean: Show navigation, true or false
      random: false,          // Boolean: Randomize the order of the slides, true or false
      pause: true,           // Boolean: Pause on hover, true or false
      pauseControls: true,    // Boolean: Pause when hovering controls, true or false
      prevText: "Previous",   // String: Text for the "previous" button
      nextText: "Next",       // String: Text for the "next" button
      maxwidth: "",           // Integer: Max-width of the slideshow, in pixels
      navContainer: ".slider",       // Selector: Where controls should be appended to, default is after the 'ul'
      manualControls: ".types-home",     // Selector: Declare custom pager navigation
      namespace: "rslides",   // String: Change the default namespace used
      before: function(){

      },   // Function: Before callback
      after: function(){

      }     // Function: After callback
    });
```